# extract string within string with out double quote

Tags: python, regex

This is just for learning purpose, I have the following code. what if i wanna extract just `'abcbc'` with out double quote? i also tried `re.search(r'\A\"(.*?)\"',a).group()` noting change.

```
>>> a = "\"abcbc\" lol"
>>> re.search(r'\A"(.*?)"',a).group()
'"abcbc"'
```

also if I change the pattern to `'\A"(.*?)'` this should just return everything after a double quote? but it gives the following. Is there anything I am wrong?

```
>>> re.search(r'\A"(.*?)',a).group()
'"'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are capturing what you want in a group, but by calling `group()` with no arguments, you are returning the entire match (group 0), not the group you want (which is group 1).  Call `.group(1)` to return the first group, which has what you want.

```
>>> a = "\"abcbc\" lol"
>>> re.search(r'\A"(.*?)"',a).group(1)
'abcbc'
```

As for your second question, `*?` is non-greedy: it will match as little as it can.  Since `*` allows matching zero, `*?` will match nothing if it can --- and it can, since you don't have anything after it to force it to match up to a certain point.  With the quote after it, it will match as little as it can provided it matches a quote next, which forces it to keep consuming text until it reaches the close quote.  But without the quote, it just matches nothing, since it has no reason to continue matching at all.

If you use a non-greedy one, it will indeed match everything after a double quote --- *everything* after the double quote, up to the end of the line:

```
>>> re.search(r'\A"(.*)',a).group()
'"abcbc" lol'
```

Comment: i think `\A"([^"]*)` would also do it (`group(1)`) of course.